# Excel Lookup Patrial Text and return the whole text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-365

I have an Excel sheet that has 1 image in each row but its not in the same column and I want them to get them all together in a column.

The other cells contain values number or texts.

I have tried with Vlookup
=VLOOKUP("*"&$F$1&"*";A2:D2;1;0)

[image]

Waiting for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as per screenshot, all other data are empty cells, try:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=TOCOL(A1:D6,1)
```

However, I do have a feeling the sample data is oversimplified, if so, try:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=BYROW(A2:D6,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP("*"&F1,x,x,,2)))
```

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake some cells contain values some not.

Comment: @illys, that's fine, I kind of expected that and amended the answer to include that option.